# Magento 2 - Is there anyway to send newsletters out faster?

Tags: newsletter

We have a list of over 12k subscribers and it currently takes 2-3 days to send. Isn't there a way to send them faster?

Comment: Which SMTP service you are using to send newsletters?

Comment: You can use third party extension also like mailchimp etc.

Comment: I'm using our local SMTP. Mailchimp does 2000 per day max so that wouldn't help.